# ArduCopter motor spins at full throttle when armed

Tags: quadcopters, troubleshooting, ardupilot

When I arm the drone the motors start rotating at some throttle percentage may be (7%) and the drone will automatically disarm after 14sec and again the process repeats after I arm the drone.

After some research, I found that this can be controlled by the parameters like `MOT_SPIN_ARMED` and `THR_MIN` but these are not available in the standard parameters list like in the video I saw.

I tried manually resetting the values like setting `MOT_SPIN_ARMED` to 0 and `THR_MIN` to 30 then the motors not started spinning when armed but when the throttle is given all motors are not in sync one motor starts at a different throttle level. I also performed all-ESC calibration and everything goes fine. But the motor yet picks up at a different speed. But when I reset the parameters the motors are all in sync as expected.

I'm not sure why I can't find the `MOT_SPIN_ARMED` in standard params. I'm really troubling with this issue any help is highly appreciated.

Firmware: Copter stable v3.2.1
Arducopter version: 2.8

Comment: Is the motor immediately spinning at a different throttle, or is it slowly gaining speed as the quad sits armed? The latter is called i-term windup and is absolutely a normal thing (and is addressed in many FAQ's for first-time builders). Do all of the motors behave normally when controlled in passthrough mode (motors tab in betaflight - I'm not experienced with ardupilot)

Comment: Motors spin immediately right after arming at full throttle (means enough throttle to lift the drone) and continues to move upto 14 seconds and disarms automatically.

Comment: Seems like potentially a protocol issue - what ESC are you using and what motor protocol do you have selected?

Answer (score 1):

Copter stable v3.2.1 is very old. I might look at updating it to a later version (4.0.7?). You can also look for the parameters `MOT_SPIN_MIN`, `MOT_SPIN_ARM` and `MOT_SPOOL_TIME`. These all work together to have the motors spinning just enough to stay on the ground but ready to take off.